# encoding textbox data for jquery json ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, encoding

I have a page saving some data from textboxes to the back end using a jquery ajax call thus:

```
function saveAsYouGo(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Report.aspx/SaveReport",
        data: "{'EditorHTML': '" + _sftabs_rTxtRep.GetHTML() + "', 'Actions' : '" + GetActions() + "', 'Notes': '" + GetNotes() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            lastHTMLVal = _sftabs_rTxtRep.GetHTML();
            alert(msg.d);
        }
      });
}
```

the GetActions and GetNotes basically just grab the text from a number of textboxes along the lines of this

```
function GetActions(){
    var na = [];
    $('#optionsTable :checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        var textVal, idVal;
        textVal = $(this).parent().parent().next("td").find("textarea").val();
        idVal = $(this).attr("id");
        if(textVal != ""){
            na.push(idVal, textVal);
        }
    });
    return na;
}
```

but when there are quotes etc in the textareas it busts the ajax call.
I have looked a bit for JSON.stringify but this doesnt seem to make any difference.
I assume that there is a way to encode the text before sending , so that I can unencode it at the other end before doing what needs doing..?

as ever any help very happily received
thanks

**EDIT**
found these little gems which help for most things

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

however the above **DO NOT WORK** for dealing with quotes as far as I can tell
and the below which suggested ditching the quotes around the data elements, didn't work at all.

```
data: {'EditorHTML': _sftabs_rTxtRep.GetHTML() , 'Actions' : GetActions(), 'Notes':GetNotes()},
```

any other ideas? this is driving me potty

**EDIT 2**

just ended up wrapping the textVal in an escape thus:

```
if(textVal != ""){
    cn.push(idVal, escape(textVal));
}
```

thanks

nat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a JSON string, just pass an object and jQuery should correctly encode it for submission:

```
data: {'EditorHTML': _sftabs_rTxtRep.GetHTML(), 'Actions' : GetActions() , 'Notes': GetNotes() }
```

From the [`$.ajax` manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (under the `data` option):

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, **if
>   not already a string.** It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

Comment: hi karim, thanks for the reply but it doesn't like that at all..Request Payload
EditorHTML=&Notes=tabs_txtCurrentH&Notes=sdgsdgs+dg+'''
Response Headers
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:91
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 26 Jul 2011 11:57:55 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
jsonerror:true

Comment: slightly red faced
didn't realise .net would be helpful and accept the JSON array as an array, changed the WebMethod to accept string[] 's and all is well

as that is what the GetActions and GetNotes() return javascript [] arrays..
did end up removing the string wrapping around the data and wrapped it all in a JSON.stringify..

doh!